# WooCommerce breadcrumb display custom posts instead of product data

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, breadcrumb

I'm working on a custom theme with some additional features for my store. To gather all promotions in one place in my store back-end and front-end, I created custom post type, custom taxonomy for it. The code for it is:

```
/**
*
* Registering custom post type 'promocja'
*
**/
function missplanner_promotion_post_type() {

    /**
    * UI Labels
    **/
    $custom_post_labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Promocje', 'post type general name', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Promocje', 'post type singular name', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Promocje', 'admin menu', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Dodaj promocję', 'add new on admin bar', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Dodaj promocję', 'promocja', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Dodaj promocję', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'Nowa promocja', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edytuj promocję', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'Zobacz promocję', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'Zobacz wszystkie promocje', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Szukaj...', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Elementy rodzice:', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'Nie znaleziono.', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nie znaleziono w koszu.', 'missplanner-official' )
    );

    /**
    * Other options
    **/
    $custom_post_args = array(
        'labels' => $custom_post_labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Wszystkie promocje Miss Planner.', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'promocja' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'promocja', $custom_post_args);

}

add_action( 'init', 'missplanner_promotion_post_type' );

/**
*
* Custom Taxonomy for post type "Promocja"
*
**/
add_action( 'init', 'missplanner_promotion_taxonomy', 0);

function missplanner_promotion_taxonomy() {

    /**
    * custom taxonomy labels
    **/
    $kategorie_promocje_labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Kategorie Promocji', 'taxonomy general name', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Kategoria Promocji', 'taxonomy singular name', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Szukaj kategorii promocji', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'Wszystkie kategorie promocji', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Kategorie Promocji rodzic', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Kategorie Promocji rodzic:', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edytuj kategorię promocji', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Aktualizuj kategorię promocji', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Dodaj nową kategorię promocji', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'Nazwa nowej kategorii promocji', 'missplanner-official' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Kategorie Promocji', 'missplanner-official' ),
    );

    /**
    * custom taxonomy args
    **/
    $kategorie_promocje_args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $kategorie_promocje_labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'promocje' ),
    );

    /**
    * Add taxonomy "Kategorie Promocji"
    **/
    register_taxonomy( 'kategorie-promocji', array( 'promocja' ), $kategorie_promocje_args );

}
```

And here is the breadcrumb on single product page (everywhere else it works just fine):
[image: wrong breadcrumb single product page woocommerce]

After setting all my custom posts as drafts, it goes back to normal.
[image]
Where should I change my code?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to reset post data in the loop `<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. I copied `single-product.php` from `woocommerce/templates` and modified it so loop starts before before_main_content hook:

```
get_header( 'shop' ); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php   
        /**
        * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
        *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    ?>
```

That way it works fine, all functionalities are maintained.